# WP Ecommerce: Display the “Order Notes” as column in the Sales Log

Tags: php, functions, plugin-wp-e-commerce

I have the following function that adds a column in the Sales Log so that I may show the Order Notes. Adding the column is good and showing the id of each item ($item->id) as test is good. Where I am getting stuck is how to display the actual order notes for each item.

Tried numerous things including ($purchlog_notes->notes);

This adds the column (all good)

```
function addPurchaseLogColumnHead( $columns ){
$columns['OrderNotes']=__('Order Notes');
    return $columns; 
}

add_filter( 'manage_dashboard_page_wpsc-purchase-logs_columns', 'addPurchaseLogColumnHead');
```

This is where I want to show Order Notes content for each sale (issue)

```
function addPurchaseLogColumnContent( $default, $column_name, $item ) {
if ($column_name == 'OrderNotes'){
        echo $item->notes;
    }
}

add_filter( 'wpsc_manage_purchase_logs_custom_column' , 'addPurchaseLogColumnContent', 10, 3);
```

So what I need is this bit **echo $item->notes;** Appreciate any ideas.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a small SQL statement to retrieve the notes:

```
global $wpdb;
$sql = $wpdb->prepare('
    SELECT notes
    FROM '.WPSC_TABLE_PURCHASE_LOGS.'
    WHERE id=%d
    ',$item->id);
echo $wpdb->get_var($sql);
```

Read more in [this post](http://haet.at/add-column-wp-ecommerce-purchase-logs/)